# Typescript - Project References - Duplicate output index.js

Tags: typescript

I'm following a book on Typescript and I wanted to separate my code by chapters. I thought about using/trying a monorepo but I end up using Typescript "Project references" functionality.

I kind of managed to do the setup but I have a duplicate index.js from the TS compilation in each of my source sub folder as well as in the 'outDir' folder I've set in the specific tsconfig.json files.

Here's the structure of my project folders - Content from the root of the project:

```
chapters/
  chap1/
    src/
      index.ts
      jsonTodoCollection.ts
      todoCollection.ts
      ... other .ts files
    tsconfig.json
  chap3/
    src/
      index.ts
    tsconfig.json
... other project files
tsconfig.json (project root tsconfig.json)
```

Here's is my project root tsconfig.json :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonJS"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./chapters/chap1"
    },
    {
      "path": "./chapters/chap3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my chap1 tsconfig.json :

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/chap1",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Here's my chapter3 tsconfig.json :

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/chap3",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

After a compilation that I run with `tsc -b -w`, the folder structure with the output becomes :

```
chapters/
  chap1/
    src/
      index.js *
      index.ts
      jsonTodoCollection.ts
      todoCollection.ts
      ... other .ts files
    tsconfig.json
  chap3/
    src/
      index.js *
      index.ts
    tsconfig.json
... other project files
dist/
  chap1/
    src/
      index.d.ts
      index.d.ts.map
      index.js *
      index.js.map
      jsonTodoCollection.d.ts
      jsonTodoCollection.d.ts.map
      jsonTodoCollection.js
      jsonTodoCollection.js.map
     ... same output files for the other .ts files in src
  chap3/
    src/
     index.d.ts
     index.d.ts.map
     index.js *
     index.js.map
tsconfig.json (project root tsconfig.json)
```

The compiled output index.js files I've highlighted with '*' are identical respective to each sub folder. The index.js file in the 'ts' src folder is generated/added after the 'outDir' is generated.

Only the index.ts is impacted

What should I do to avoid that duplicate index.js compilation output in the ts source folder ?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer in the Documentation about Project References.

In the `Guidance` section, about the `Overall Structure` :

> ... Another good practice is to have a “solution” tsconfig.json file that simply has references to all of your leaf-node projects and sets files to an empty array (otherwise the solution file will cause double compilation of files). Note that starting with 3.0, it is no longer an error to have an empty files array if you have at least one reference in a tsconfig.json file.

So the solution to my problem is to set in the root project `tsconfig.json` file, a `file` setting with an empty array `[]` :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonJS"
  },
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./chapters/chap1"
    },
    {
      "path": "./chapters/chap3"
    },

  ]
}
```